# Can Xbox Music be configured to recognize "Band Name" and "The Band Name" as the same band?

Tags: windows-8, music, tags, id3, xbox-music

In Xbox Music, "Band Name" and "The Band Name" are grouped as two different bands. This can be frustrating, especially if the band's name starts with a letter nowhere near "T".

As a corollary, can Xbox Music sort "The Band Name" as if it started with 'B'?

Edit: Here is an example.

Near the top (with the 'A's):

[image]

Near the bottom (with the 'T's):

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example band?  I've never seen this before.

Comment: @cowgod: See my edit.

Comment: Sorry, I still need more clarification.  Are your screenshots showing music on your computer (non-DRM), or music from the marketplace, either streamed or added to your music library via Xbox Music Pass?

Comment: @cowgod: All of it is on my hard drive (non-DRM). I don't have Xbox Music Pass. Additionally, all of it is in mp3 format (some acquired as mp3s, from converted to mp3 from ripped flac).

Answer (score 2):

Based on your screenshots, it looks like you are using the "Albums" sort method, not the "Artist" sort method.  Most likely, the music has been tagged differently for each of these albums.  The old Zune software (predecessor to Xbox Music) supported [two tags that were "hidden" inside the MP3 metadata](http://www.insidethecircle.net/2011/08/zunetip-zune-48-includes-new-options.html):

- Sort Album Title
- Sort Album Artist

These tags are used to change how the Zune software would display/sort albums.  There is a good chance that the new Xbox Music on Windows 8 also supports these tags.  It is also possible that you have a different "Album Artist" tag for the different albums ("The American Analog Set" vs. "American Analog Set).

You can edit the MP3 metadata using File Explorer on the desktop of Windows 8 by using the details pane, as shown here:

[image: File Explorer - Edit MP3 Metadata]

You can also try the [Zune software](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/zune/software/download), [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) or [Mp3Tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) to edit your MP3 tags.  There are many other programs that can tag MP3s as well, those are just a few.